# How to develop basic graphics for Android, given limitations of emulators?

Tags: android

I'm developing a simple card game for Android and I'm facing the graphical problem. I found that a good option would be using AndEngine. However, it seems that is not supported neither by emulator nor by Android-x86, while it works fine on real device. Unfortunately I have only one real device but I need to test it with at least two devices (then I need the emulator or Virtual Machine). So, I have few options:

- Develop a full version using AndEngine to be deployed on real device, while running a limited version with a GUI made of text and buttons on the emulator.
- Develop it using only Android APIs

The only "graphical effects" I need are the following:

- moving an image when discarding a card
- partially cover a card with another card as I need to display 8 cards together

Then my question are:

- which approach is better?
- Would be actually possible to make it using only Android APIs (buttons, images, etc.)?
- Is it possible to free paint images on a panel in the same way we do it in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Surface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html)s, using the `draw(Canvas canvas)` method?

Comment: It seems good, I try to do some tests with it while I wait for other opinions, thanks!